# select only required text in oracle without hardcoding the character position

Tags: oracle

I have a column in database which stores data like follows

```
{0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO]",{1}="SomeText"
```

I want to get the 0th value ie `DYD666020115982-ZO` printed in output.

I have tried `SUBSTR({0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO]",{1}="SomeText",7,18)` which gives me output, but I wanted to know is there any other way without hard coding the position.

Comment: Why was it down voted?

Comment: No idea. The question looks OK to me - shows sample data, shows desired result, shows what you tried ... I don't see any reason for downvoting (so I upvoted it).

Comment: Will you ever have data where the elements are out of order? For example: `{1}="SomeText",{0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO]"`

Comment: No, it will always start from 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oldfashioned `substr + instr` combination works good, works fast (`res_1`).

Regexp (`res_2`) along with `trim`s (because of parenthesis) is another option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '{0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO]",{1}="SomeText"' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '[') + 1,
  4                     instr(col, ']') - instr(col, '[') - 1
  5               ) res_1,
  6         --
  7         rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(col, '\[.+\]'), '['), ']') res_2
  8  from test;

RES_1              RES_2
------------------ ------------------
DYD666020115982-ZO DYD666020115982-ZO

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to match the pattern `(^|,)\{0\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, list ) AS
SELECT 1, '{0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO]",{1}="SomeText"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '{1}="SomeText with a \"Quote\"",{0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO]"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '{1}="SomeText"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '{0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO-2]",{1}="SomeText",{0}="[DYD666020115982-ZO-1]"' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '{1}="{0}=\"[DYD666020115982-ZO]\""' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( list, '(^|,)\{0\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS value
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | VALUE                  |
> | :--------------------- |
> | [DYD666020115982-ZO]   |
> | [DYD666020115982-ZO]   |
> | null                   |
> | [DYD666020115982-ZO-2] |
> | null                   |
> ```

or, if you want to string the leading and training characters then:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( value, 2, LENGTH( value ) - 2 ) AS value
FROM   (
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( list, '(^|,)\{0\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS value
  FROM   test_data
)
```

which outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE                |
> | :------------------- |
> | DYD666020115982-ZO   |
> | DYD666020115982-ZO   |
> | null                 |
> | DYD666020115982-ZO-2 |
> | null                 |
> ```

---

If you want to get all the values then you can use a recursive sub-query and `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

**Query**:

```sql
WITH data ( id, list, key, value, idx, max_idx ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         list,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( list, '\{(\d+)\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( list, '\{(\d+)\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( list, '\{(\d+)\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)' )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         list,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( list, '\{(\d+)\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)', 1, idx + 1, NULL, 1 ) ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( list, '\{(\d+)\}="(([^"]|\\")*?)"(,|$)', 1, idx + 1, NULL, 2 ),
         idx + 1,
         max_idx
  FROM   data
  WHERE  idx < max_idx
)
SELECT id, key, value
FROM   data
WHERE  idx <= max_idx
ORDER BY id, key
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | KEY | VALUE                       
> -: | --: | :---------------------------
>  1 |   0 | [DYD666020115982-ZO]        
>  1 |   1 | SomeText                    
>  2 |   0 | [DYD666020115982-ZO]        
>  2 |   1 | SomeText with a \"Quote\"   
>  3 |   1 | SomeText                    
>  4 |   0 | [DYD666020115982-ZO-2]      
>  4 |   0 | [DYD666020115982-ZO-1]      
>  4 |   1 | SomeText                    
>  5 |   1 | {0}=\"[DYD666020115982-ZO]\"
> ```

If you just want the values where the `key` is `0` then add `AND key = 0` to the end of the query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d93e6ca6711dc5d7b39d6cc4930c60b6)*